# How to split a NSDecimalnumber between decimal & integer & back

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, math, nsdecimalnumber

I can't figure how get the integral & decimal value from a NSDecimalnumber.

For example, if I have 10,5, how get 10 & 5?

And if I have 10 & 5, how return to 10,5?

---

Mmm ok, that is looking better!

However I have the concer about lossing decimals.

This is for a app that will be international. If for example a user set the price "124,2356" I wanna load & save the exact number.

---

Mmm ok, that is the way, but not respect the # of decimal places. If exist a way to know that from the current local I'm set.

This is because that represent currency values...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm using 2 for the scale since you said this was for currency but you may choose to use another rounding scale. I'm also ignoring any exceptions rounding may bring since this is a pretty simple example.

```
NSDecimalNumberHandler *behavior = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundDown scale:0 raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];
NSDecimalNumber *price = /* eg. 10.5 */;
NSDecimalNumber *dollars = [price decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior: behavior];
NSDecimalNumber *cents = [price decimalNumberBySubtracting: dollars];
```

That will give you 10 and 0.5 in the `dollars` and `cents` variables respectively. If you want whole numbers you can use this method to multiply your `cents` by a power of 10.

```
cents = [cents decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10: 2];
```

Which will in turn multiply you `cents` by 100, giving you 10 and 5 in `dollars` and `cents`. You should also know that you can use negative powers of 10 here to divide.

So,

```
cents = [cents decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10: -2];
```

would undo that last method.

Comment: should it not be 0 for scale? Using a scale of 2, a price of 10.5 will   round giving dollars of 10.5. Subtracting that from price will give cents of 0

Comment: I believe this doesn't work when the number is negative, since `RoundDown` rounds away from zero then according to <https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsroundingmode?language=objc>. And would be simple to switch between Up or Down rounding modes based on negative value except testing for a negative value is not straightforward, easiest to do `num.doubleValue >= 0`. At least `Decimal` in Swift exposes a `sign` property.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Math functions objective c has but something like

```
Math.floor(10.5) = 10
(10.5 - 10) * 10 = 5
```

bit of a clearer example (cos of the 10's)

```
Math.floor(20.4) = 20
(20.4 - 20) * 10 = 4;
```

The other problem

```
(5 / 10) = .5
10 + .5 = 10.5
```

The 10 used on the decimal points depends on the amount of decimal places... for instance

```
Math.floor(20.44) = 20
(20.44 - 20) * 100 = 44;
```

requires you to times by 100

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the math fns, this may work:

```
double val = [dn doubleValue]; // dn is a NSDecimalNumber*
int intPart = (int) val;
double doublePart = (val - intPart);
```

This may give you some trouble, the loop may never terminate, in that case you will have to put a counter in there:

```
while (doublePart != (int)doublePart) doublePart*=10;
```

Answer (score -1):

`double floor (double x);` is a POSIX function. This function can be used to find the highest integer value not greater than `x`.

```
double x = 10.5;

double y = floor (x);
// y = 10.0

double z = x - y;
// z = 0.5
```